# How to implement an own generator to be used with std distributions

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I would like to use a random number generator I implemented with some of the distributions from the C++11 `<random>` library.

Is there an interface my generator class has to adhere to so an instance of it can be passed to the `operator()` method of a distribution?

Or is there base class from which I must derive my class?

Comment: If you check the reference, it states what is required: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomBitGenerator

Comment: It sounds like you may be confusing runtime-dispatch through interfaces with the compile-time binding of a functor.  Operator() is bound to templates at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface has to match the [UniformRandomBitGenerator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomBitGenerator) concept:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Expression      | Return type  | Requirements                                                                                          |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| G::result_type  | T            | T is an unsigned integer type                                                                         |
| G::min()        | T            | Returns the smallest value that G's operator() may return. The value is strictly less than G::max().  |
| G::max()        | T            | Returns the largest value that G's operator() may return. The value is strictly greater than G::min() |
| g()             | T            | Returns a value in the closed interval [G::min(), G::max()]. Has amortized constant complexity.       |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You do not have to derive from a base class as the binding happens at compile time.

Here is a toy example of a generator that matches the interface:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class MyGen
{
public:
  using result_type = int;
  static constexpr result_type min() { return 0; }
  static constexpr result_type max() { return 99; }
  result_type operator()() { return rand() % 100; }
};

int main()
{
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{1, 6};
  MyGen gen;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cout << dist(gen) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```